# GCC/G++ addresses and can't read the registers

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb, g++

```
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x000000000000071a <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000000000000071b <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000071e <+4>: sub    rsp,0x20
   0x0000000000000722 <+8>: mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x000000000000072b <+17>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x000000000000072f <+21>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x0000000000000731 <+23>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x20]
   0x0000000000000735 <+27>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000000738 <+30>:    call   0x764 <Test::Test()>
   0x000000000000073d <+35>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x20]
   0x0000000000000741 <+39>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000000744 <+42>:    call   0x7ae <Test::a()>
   0x0000000000000749 <+47>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000000000074e <+52>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x0000000000000752 <+56>:    xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x000000000000075b <+65>:    je     0x762 <main()+72>
   0x000000000000075d <+67>:    call   0x5f0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x0000000000000762 <+72>:    leave  
   0x0000000000000763 <+73>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I have a problem.. I'm trying to debug the program but the addresses are weird and I can't read the registers(after start).    `"The program has no registers now."`
and that's happens at any program that I've compiled in my computer.

EDIT:

```
gef➤  break*0x0000000000000763
Breakpoint 1 at 0x763: file 1.cpp, line 36.
gef➤  r 
Starting program: /root/Desktop/Challenges/AdvancedMemoryChallenges/1.bin 
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x763

gef➤  info reg $rip
rip            0x7ffff7dd9c20   0x7ffff7dd9c20
gef➤ 
gef➤  start
[+] Breaking at '{int (void)} 0x55555555471a <main()>'
[!] Command 'entry-break' failed to execute properly, reason: Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x763
```

Comment: This is way underspecified. How do you build it, how do you start it, and so on? Might be a bit off-topic, really ...

Comment: Could you clarify your question in an [edit]?

Comment: I've edited the question, I wish that you understand the problem. :P

Comment: Can you show us the output you get (by editing the question) when you type `start` followed by `info reg $rip` ?

Comment: I see that `info reg $rip` succeeds. What command did you run that led to the `"The program has no registers now."` error?

Comment: >info registers command & see the addresses, little weird no?

Comment: So `info reg $rip` succeeds but, at the same point in your session, `info reg` gives an error?

Comment: nope, nothing :\

Comment: just the "The program has no registers now." message

Comment: But there no anywhere in your output `info registers` and `The program has no registers now.`.

Comment: I guess you are debugging this code https://github.com/ewimberley/AdvancedMemoryChallenges/blob/master/1.cpp?

Comment: yep, you guess right

Answer (score 1):

`0x763` is an address before relocation. (It is unclear whether it is from an object file or the actual executable.)

The addresses of code in a running program are never this low in the address space.

You need to set a breakpoint on `_start` or `main`, start the program, and see which addresses the kernel assigns to the machine code in question.  The GDB `disassemble` command print will print such addresses.

GDB automatically disables address space layout randomization (ASLR), so the addresses will be constant as long as you do not change the program, its libraries, or the kernel (which sometimes results in process layout changes, too).